# How do I map an application/json POST request to the params in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am being passed in a json body for a post request, but i'm not sure the best way to map this json body to request params in rails:

```
{
   username: "example-user",
   password: "password",
   email: "example@gmail.com",
}
```

and in the controller i wish to acccess params["username"], 
is this possible? how should i do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

see the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-xml-parameters) for a comprehensive information.

you can simply access to `params[:username]` or even `params['username']` since params is a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

Note that you can easily inspect the params using the debugger gem, or just slam a `raise` in your controller action to see them on the error page when in development mode.

Comment: But only if the request has the `Content-Type: application/json` header, otherwise Rails creates a parameter with the name of the entire POST body and no value :)

Comment: These days, `binding.pry` is the way to go. Trivially searchable if you accidentally leave a stray one in and way more useful when it triggers. You can even set up pre-commit hooks to catch them. Doing a raise for debug purposes is kinda gross and likely to cause havoc if one ever gets deployed to production, and unlike debugger or `binding.pry`, you don't want to be blocking all exceptions with a pre-commit hook.

Comment: agreed, using `raise` is bad practice, just mentioned it here for the sake of completeness. These days I use Rubymine's debugger, it's even cleaner (no need to add anything to your source, just add a breakpoint) - this and scm integration are pretty much the only reasons I use an IDE over just vim ;). Note : binding.pry requires the pry gem, which is not part of vanilla rails